# PHP & MySQL - Checking if database entry does NOT exist?

Tags: php, mysql, database, compare, mediawiki

I'm collecting the birthdates of users in my system, doing so by linking the the user's unique ID to their birthday entry in another table.

To prevent users from accidentally/purposefully entering two birthdate entries for their accounts, I'd like to remove to the entry form for birthdays **IF** the user has already entered a birthday prior.

For instance:

```
$value = mysqli_query("SELECT bd_user_id FROM user_birthdate WHERE
bd_user_id="$user_id";");
```

From that data, how will I be able to return some form value to determine if whether the user's ID has already been index in **user_birthdate** or not? (Where **$user_id** = The current user's ID)

Or perhaps I'm taking the wrong approach here? The logic behind it is what's been getting me.

How can I check if whether a value is **NOT** indexed in a database table?

Comment: Probably better to use `SELECT count(*)` so you always get a return value.  In this case would be 0 or 1, as long as bd_user_id is a primary key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You normally query the database as you did

```
$value = mysqli_query("SELECT bd_user_id FROM user_birthdate WHERE bd_user_id="$user_id";");
```

Than you use mysqli_num_rows(), and check if it returns 0.

```
$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($value);
if($num_rows > 0){
    //exists
}else{
    //doesn't exist
}
```

**Sorry, as Devon said in your case it's mysqli_num_rows not mysql_num_rows.

Comment: Whoops my bad....didnt see your answer yet...Ill remove mine, since its almost the exact same